OpenCascadeShape does not appear to work for sphere object - no wire mesh formed
I tried a simple example using OpenCascadeShape, and BALL works as an option, but sphere does not - I get an error -
OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[OpenCascadeShape[Sphere[{1,
2,3},10]]] is not a type of graphics
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"]

shape1 = OpenCascadeShape[Ball[{1, 0, 0}]]
shape2 = OpenCascadeShape[Ball[{0, 1/2, 0}, 1/2]]
shape5 = OpenCascadeShape[Sphere[{1, 2, 3}, 10]]


Area[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 10]]

OpenCascadeShapeType[shape1]
OpenCascadeShapeType[shape2]
OpenCascadeShapeType[shape5]

bmesh1 = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[shape1]

bmesh2 = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[shape2]

bmesh5 = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[shape5]



Show[bmesh1["Wireframe"], bmesh2["Wireframe"] ]
Show[bmesh5["Wireframe"] ]


